# Multiple OnClick in same component Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios

Is it possible to call multiple handleClick or handleSelect ? In my component, I need to do that and i don't now if I need to change just the name like that handleSelect_2 or something else.
This is my code

```
handleClick() {
  let config = {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${authentication.getToken()}`
    }
  };
  axios
    .post(
      `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sessions/${this.state.session_id}/students/${
        this.state.selectedStudent
      }`,
      {},
      config
    )
    .then(response => {
      this.props.history.push("/Sessions");
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

handleSelect(event) {
  this.setState({ selectedStudent: event.target.value });
}
```

I just need to do the same method but with an other post method.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you want to call both the handleSelect and handleClick at the same time?

Comment: No, I need to make an other post but based on the same method. I gonna change the url of the post and the data in. Here I add students  to a session. I need to add "themes" and "teachers" to a sessions

Comment: So a user lets a student or teacher from a dropdown(`handleselect`), then you go fetch the teacher, students and themes on the click?

Comment: Yes it's that. Just not on the same button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can rename your onClick handlers like below but with different urls

```
handleStudentClick()
handleTeacherClick()
handleThemesClick()
```

its better to separate them as it will make it easy for you to maintain as your application grows.

for your selects(dropwdowns) just include a name attribute that is the same value as the property name in the state

```
<select name="selectedStudent" onChange={this.handleSelect}></select>
<select name="selectedTeacher" onChange={this.handleSelect} ></select>
<select name="selectedTheme" onChange={this.handleSelect} ></select>
```

Then you can change your `handleselect` to

```
handleSelect(event) {
  let updateState = this.setState;
  updateState[event.target.name] = event.target.value
  this.setState(updateState );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
   onClick(event) {
      func1();
      func2();
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <a href="#" onClick={this.onClick}>Test Link</a>
      );
   }
}
```